# how do shortlinks work? (inside google)

Tags: networking, shortcut

I found out that inside google , shortlinks are used to navigate around to different Google services. For example:

**go/mail** would take you to gmail

**go/docs** would take you to docs

And that is entered in the address bar of the browser .

I'm just wondering if anyone knows how it works ? is it internal DNS mapping ?

Comment: do you mean inside google chrome?

Comment: Or, do you mean inside Google's corporate network?

Comment: I mean inside google's corporate network .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how it *does* work, but I know how it *could* work.

Create a computer called "go". Set up DNS mapping so "ping go" does something useful.

On that computer run a web server which, when "http://go/mail" is fetched, responds with HTTP status code 302 (redirect).